# Implementing a linux systemcall for reboot

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls, reboot

I am trying to implement a system call in linux to reboot the system after the amount of seconds passed(syscall argument).
I am new to linux and operating systems, any help will be appreciated.

i am having trouble because in /kernel/sys.c it does not allow me to use system() or sleep(), the error is that it is an implicit declaration..... when i try to make.

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(myrestart, int, msg)
{
    int timer = msg * 35;
    sleep(timer);
    system("shutdown -r now");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can only use what the kernel provides inside the kernel. You can’t use the C library. Also I’m pretty sure you shouldn’t just sleep in a syscall ever.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work. If you define a system call, you are in kernel context. In kernel context you cannot call libraries that are part of the c std library. You can only call functions that are part of the kernel. In addition shutdown is a user space command. If you are interested how reboot is implemented, have a look at kernel/reboot.c.